# Add same value into string multiple times

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to make a simple tab space between words, using a dynamic ammount. How would I do this?

Simply like this:

```
string p1 = keysC[pos]+"="+valsC[pos];
int tabs = (60 - p1.Length) / 4;
wr.WriteLine(p1 + ("\t" * tabs) +"//"+comsC[pos]);
```

Comment: what are you asking for ? What doesn't work ? What is the expected result ? Is this a question or an answer ?

Comment: Side note: not everyone have tabs set to 4 (I believe in most cases default is actually 8). Consider instead padding with spaces (almost same code, but will display properly in more cases).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`String` contructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overload for that.

```
string p1 = keysC[pos]+"="+valsC[pos];
int tabs = (60 - p1.Length) / 4;
wr.WriteLine(p1 + new string('\t', tabs) +"//"+comsC[pos]);
```

Note that the first argument of the constructor is a `char` and not a `string`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`string` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string allTabs = new string('\t', tabs);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string spacing = new String('\t', tabs);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like just need to write a function that repeats the same string N number of times

```
static string RepeatString(string source, int times) { 
  var builder = new StringBuilder(source.Length * times);
  for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    builder.Append(source);
  }
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

Note that if you only care about repeating a `char` like `\t` then use @Vache's answer of `new string(theChar, theCount)`

Comment: +1. Or even `String.Join(null, Enumerable.Repeat(source, times));`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: which would be less efficient than the constructor.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - indeed for of single character as in actual OP's case one should use constructor.